# CMake For Google Test

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, cmake, googletest

I am trying to follow this tutorial for running a Google Tests file but I am having some trouble with the `CMakeLists.txt`.

https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

what exactly is runTests here? Is it my program's main() file? How should I replace it according to my program? Currently, I have this error when I use `make`:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'runTests' failed
make[2]: *** [runTests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all
```

main.cpp: (I tried moving this part to the end of the tests.cpp file too but still didn't work)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
   return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class Player
{

    int inventory;

public:
    Player();
    int decreaseInventory(int numOfBeers);
    void setInventory(int newInventory);
    int getBackOrder();
    int getCost();
    int getInventory();

    bool operator ==(Player& p);
};

Player::Player()
{
    cout << " Default Player Constructor\n";
    inventory = 12;
    backorder = 0;
    cost = 0;
    orderDelay = 0;
    shipmentDeplay = 0;
}

void Player::setInventory(int newInventory)
{
    inventory = newInventory;
}

int Player::decreaseInventory(int numOfBeers)
{
    inventory = inventory - numOfBeers;
}

int Player::getInventory()
{
    return inventory;
}


#endif
```

tests.cpp

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "Player.h"

TEST(playerTest, decreaseInventoryTest ) {

    Player p;
    int curr_inv = p.getInventory();
    EXPECT_EQ(curr_inv-3, p.decreaseInventory(3));

}
```

How can I run my tests?

Comment: FWIW, the tutorial is a bit dated, particularly as it pertains to the CMake file. The use of `include_directories()` is discouraged, as it has been superseded. Also, the imported `GTest::GTest` target should be preferred when using the [FindGTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGTest.html) module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly is runTests here? Is it my program's main() file? How should I replace it according to my program?

`runTests` is the name of an executable that you're trying to build.  It needs a `main` just like any executable will, and there are two options: 1) write your own or 2) use the one provided with gtest.  If you want to go with option 1, add `main.cpp` to the `add_executable` line.

```
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp main.cpp)
```

The better option in my opinion is to use the `main` provided by GTest, since it gives you some command line arguments.  You can use that by adding it to your `target_link_libraries` line.

```
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Comment: Do I need to recompile my main.cpp or something else if I change my code? Currently if I run ./runTests, it keeps saying that the test has failed. Tho everything else looks correct to me.  ```Expected: curr_inv-3
      Which is: 9
To be equal to: p.decreaseInventory(3)
      Which is: 1862945232```

Comment: `make` should rebuild all targets that depend on your changed files.  1862945232 looks like something's either been uninitialized or underflowed, so I'd suggest using `gdb` to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Fixed it! I had forgotten to return values from decreaseInventory();

Answer (score 0):

Check the official guide https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html

```
FetchContent_Declare(...)

target_link_libraries(
  runTests
  gtest_main
)
```